# Как можно упростить этот `чудо` код?

Tags: javascript

Привет, есть текущее положение (cur), максимальное значение (maxcur) нужно знать предыдущее и следующее:

```
cur = 0;       // current
maxcur = 5;    // maximum current
next = 1;      // init next frame
prev = maxcur; // init prev frame

function playMe(delta){
   // delta can be +1 or -1 (left/right)

   cur = cur + delta;
   if (cur>maxcur) cur = 0; if (cur<0) cur = maxcur;
   next = cur + 1; if (next>maxcur) next = 0;
   prev = cur - 1; if (prev<0) prev = maxcur;

   // any action with current,next and prev frames
}

$('#left').click(function(){ playMe(1); });
$('#right').click(function(){ playMe(-1); });
```

По сути получается обычный сдвиг, писал так всегда, а тут взглянул аж 4 условия (if) на одну итерацию. может быть есть способ сделать проще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

так:

```
cur = (cur+maxcur+delta)%maxcur;
next = (cur+1)%maxcur;
prev = (cur+maxcur-1)%maxcur;
```

зы только maxcur надо +1 сделать, а то это будет 0..maxcur-1...

Comment: Я поэтому и спросил, никак не могу догнать этот чёртов остаток от деления. Я сделал удобный фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/tZt82/ если вас не затруднит, можете внедрить этот код?

Comment: Ах всё спасибо догнал ваше "ЗЫ"!!!